# How to declare public static class fields in PHP4

Tags: class, static, php4, static-members

Do you have the solutions that public static class fields in PHP4

```
var static $field = null;
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC, expecting T_VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 4 didn't support static properties natively.  The best you could do was implement static variables inside of your methods.  Maybe the following link is useful for you:

http://adam.bregenzer.net/php/static_class_properties